# I keep getting TypeError on mongoose-paginate method;

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I keep getting:

> TypeError undefined paginate function

Here's the code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');
var paginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
});

ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  hosts: [
    'localhost:9200'
  ]});

ProductSchema.plugin(paginate);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

In router.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   Product.paginate({}, { page: 3, limit: 10 }, function(err, result) {

   });
});
```

I got this error in `router.js`, it keeps saying:

> TypeError undefined paginate function

Comment: What version of mongoose do you use?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr Im using version "^4.2.4",

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and I googled around to no avail (other similar issues listed below)

I console.logged mongoose-paginate and it turned out to be a function which accepted a schema. I called it on my schema and it works for me now.

mongoose-paginate:^5.0.0

```
// Load required packages
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamp');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

// Define our Question schema
var QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    type: {type: String, required: true},
    options: [String]
});

//Add auto timestamping
QuestionSchema.plugin(timestamps);

//Add Pagination
mongoosePaginate(QuestionSchema);

// Export the Mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('questions', QuestionSchema);
```

Node: v4.4.3

npm: 2.15.1

mongoose: ^4.4.12

If that doesn't help, you can try these sources out:

[mongoose-paginate Issue#9](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate/issues/9)

[mongoose-paginate Issue#71](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate/issues/71)